# "graduate from" vs. "graduating from"

Tags: grammar, british-english

Basically I want to say I am graduated today. Here is the sentences: 
it is a huge honour to graduate from a top university such as ...... .

It is correct? or it must be "to be graduating".
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct and usable, but "to be graduating" is better here.

"Graduate" is a more general term - *I graduated, I will graduate, I graduate* - is refers more to the fact of the graduation achievement.  You can be proud of graduating from that university, but you can say something like "I graduated from this university two years ago" without necessarily feeling honored.

"To be graduating," however, applies to the specific occasion on which you are giving the speech - the achievement ceremony being then and there, your classmates and professors present, etc.  Nobody expects you to feel honored every time you mention graduating from your university in the future, but it certainly makes a lot of sense to feel honored at the moment.  It is a stylistically better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence "It is a huge honour to graduate from a top university such as..." is correct and appropriate at any moment, but I think **"great honor"** sounds better than **"huge honor"**.